# new line automatic trim's inside div in html

Tags: javascript, html

**My acutal data in response:**
10 set COUNTER1 to 5  
20 set COUNTER2 to 5 
30 set LIMIT1 to 3 
40 set LIMIT2 to 4 
50 do until COUNTER1 < LIMIT1 
60 do until COUNTER2 < LIMIT2 
70 print LETTER-TABLE(COUNTER1, COUNTER2) 
80 COUNTER2 = COUNTER2 – 1 
90 enddo 
100 COUNTER1 = COUNTER1 – 1 
110 set COUNTER2 to 5 
120 enddo

Consider the above pseudo-code which prints values contained in the table below. 
What will be the last value printed by the pseudo-code?

F O H M Q
S K T W P
D C A R U
E G I N L
X B J Y Z

**My data render in div:**

10 set COUNTER1 to 5 20 set COUNTER2 to 5 30 set LIMIT1 to 3 40 set LIMIT2 to 4 50 do until COUNTER1 < LIMIT1 60 do until COUNTER2 < LIMIT2 70 print LETTER-TABLE(COUNTER1, COUNTER2) 80 COUNTER2 = COUNTER2 – 1 90 enddo 100 COUNTER1 = COUNTER1 – 1 110 set COUNTER2 to 5 120 enddo Consider the above pseudo-code which prints values contained in the table below. What will be the last value printed by the pseudo-code? F O H M Q S K T W P D C A R U E G I N L X B J Y Z [QuestionType = MultipleChoice, Marks = 2]

I want to display in div as it is getting in response?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace `\n` by their HTML equivalents: `<br>`

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById("input")
var data = document.getElementById("data")
var changed = document.getElementById("changed")

function toDivs() {
  data.innerHTML = input.value
  changed.innerHTML = input.value.replace(/(\n|\r\n|\n\r)/g, '<br>')
}

toDivs()
textarea.addEventListener("keyup", toDivs)
```

```css
div { margin-top: 1em; }
#data { color: blue; }
#changed { color: green; }
```

```html
<textarea id="input">Hello
world
</textarea>
<div id="data"></div>
<div id="changed"></div>
```

Documentation: [String.prototype.replace() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)